# Ruby object in partial view not accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial-views

I have a partial view, "_foo.html.erb" that I am attempting to render from another view like so:

```
<%= render @my_foo_obj %>
```

My partial looks something like this:

```
Some text
<%= foo.title %>
```

My problem is "Some text" gets rendered, but the value of "foo.title" does not get rendered. I have verified that the value of "foo.title" does get rendered if I try to access it from the original view I am trying to render the partial from. Obvisouly, Ruby is using the correct partial, I just can't access the object for some reason.

Any thoughts?

Comment: the `@variables` are shared between Action/views and partials, you can directly use `@my_foo_obj` in your partial ;) -- to answer your question: `<%= render @my_foo_obj, foo: @my_foo_obj %>` will create the local variable `foo` (equal to `@my_foo_obj`) available only in the partial

Comment: That doesn't work either :(

Comment: If it does not show any error, maybe the title attribute of the foo object returns nil or an empty string. Because calling foo.title would normally raise a NoMethodError "title" for Nil:NilClass.

Comment: Like I said, I verified the title attribute is not nil by accessing it in the view (not the partial)

Comment: Is it an empty string?

Comment: No, it's a value I am expecting.

Comment: try `<%= foo.inspect %>` to see if this foo object is present and see all its attributes

Comment: That doesn't give me anything...

Comment: `_foo.html.rb` ← shouldn't that be `.erb`?

Comment: @Stefan sorry, typo. Fixed.

Comment: Hmmm, what is the actual name of your partial?

Comment: "_config_diff.html.erb"

Comment: So you're trying to print `<%= config_diff.title %>`?

Comment: @Stefan that is correct.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39016/discussion-between-stefan-and-anthv123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had another partial with the same name that the implicit render was using instead. Lesson learned: make sure multiple views are not named the same thing :)

By the way, Jason Kim's answer did work, I just want to use the implicit render functionality.

Comment: You should remove this question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= render partial: "foo", locals: {foo: @my_foo_obj} %>
```

I am assuming the partial file in the same folder as the view you are trying to render.

---

Some explanation

Basically, your original code wasn't rendering the partial "_foo.html.erb".

`partial: "foo"` indicates that you want to render a partial "_foo.html.erb".

`locals: {foo: @my_foo_obj}` says that you are passing a local variable to the partial. And that local variable is named `foo` and it will have `@my_foo_obj` as the value.

Comment: That works! Still would be nice to know why my original code isn't working

Comment: Hey, see my edited response. I added some explanation about the code.

Comment: @JasonKim you can call `render object` and Rails will look up a partial according to `object`'s class